# How does the tautological one-form convert a velocity to a momentum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, canonical-conjugation

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_one-form) on the "tautological one-form" $\theta$ says that it

> is used to create a correspondence between the velocity of a point in a mechanical system and its momentum, thus providing a bridge between Lagrangian mechanics and Hamiltonian mechanics

and that

> velocities are appropriate for the Lagrangian formulation of classical mechanics, but in the Hamiltonian formulation, one works with momenta, and not velocities; the tautological one-form is a device that converts velocities $\dot{q}$ into momenta $p$.

I certainly understand why this device is physically useful, but unfortunately, the Wikipedia doesn't explicitly explain how $\theta$ maps $\dot{q}$ to $p$.

In order to make sure that I understand the tautological one-form correctly, I'd like to explain it in very concrete detail with a minimum of mathematical formalism; if anything below is incorrect, then please let me know. As I understand it, $\theta$ is constructed via the following steps:

1. We start with the configuration space, which is represented by an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $Q$. The velocities $v := \dot{q}$ live in the tangent space $TQ$.
2. The cotangent bundle $T^*Q$ is a $2n$-dimensional smooth manifold that can (loosely) be thought of as the set of all ordered pairs $(q, p|_q)$, where $q \in Q$ and $p|_q$ is a one-form that linearly maps the tangent space $T_qQ$ at the point $q$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
3. $q$ and $p|_q$ both have $n$ degrees of freedom, so the cotangent space $T^*Q$ is a $2n$-dimensional smooth manifold. It can therefore be locally parameterized by local coordinate charts $(U \subset T^*Q) \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, which we can split up into $2n$ different coordinate charts $(U \subset T^*Q) \to \mathbb{R}$ that we'll call $q^i,\ i = 1, \dots, n$ and $p_j,\ j = 1, \dots, n$, where we've [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates#Definition_on_cotangent_bundles) the cotangent bundle geometry to distinguish the $q^i$ from the $p_j$. Specifically, we separate the coordinate charts such that the $n$ charts $q^i$ only depend nontrivially on the first argument $q$ in each $(q,p|_q) \in T^*Q$, while the other $n$ coordinate charts $p_j$ can depend nontrivially on both $q$ and $p|_q$. These are just coordinate charts $(U \subset T^*Q) \to \mathbb{R}$, not vectors or one-forms or tensors of any kind.
4. Fix an ordered pair $m = (q, p|_q) \in T^*Q$, where $q \in Q$ and $p|_q \in T^*_q$ map to a fixed set of $2n$ real numbers $q^i(m)$ and $p_i(m)$.
5. The tautological one-form corresponding to the element $m \in T^*Q$ is the fixed linear functional
   $$\theta_m := \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(m)\ dq^i(m).$$
   Despite the notation, the sum on $i$ is not a tensor contraction, but just a plain old sum.

If we now let $m$ vary over $T^*Q$, then we get a one-form
$$\theta \in T^*T^*Q := \{(m, \theta_m) | m \in T^*Q\}$$
over the whole cotangent bundle manifold $T^*Q$.

For a given $i$, $q^i$ is a real-valued function of (an open subset of) the $2n$-dimensional cotangent bundle smooth manifold $T^*Q$. The one-form $\theta$ over $T^*Q$ is therefore technically $2n$-dimensional. But as mentioned above, we used the contangent-bundle structure of $T^*Q$ to separate out the coordinate charts $q^i$ and $p_i$ so that the $n$ functions $q^i$ only depend nontrivially on the $q \in Q$ in the element $(q, p|_q) \in T^*Q$. But each summand (with fixed $i$) in the definition of $\theta$ is a one-form that points along one of the coordinate basis directions $dq^i$, and none of the summands point along a $dp_j$ direction. So while the linear functional $\theta_m$ technically acts on a $2n$-dimensional space, it is only nonzero within the $n$-dimensional subspace spanned by the $dq^i$. The defining map $m \to \theta_m$ technically maps the $2n$-dimensional cotangent bundle $T^*Q$ to $T^*_mT^*Q$, the $2n$-dimensional dual space spanned by the $dq^i$ and $dp_j$. But the image of this map lies entirely with the $n$-dimensional dual subspace spanned by the $dq^i$, so without loss of generality we can restrict the target space down to that dual subspace and think of the defining map $m \to \theta_m$ as a map from the $2n$-dimensional cotangent bundle $T^*Q$ to the only $n$-dimensional dual space $T^*_mQ$.

Is everything above correct (or at least correct enough for a physics level of rigor)?

If so, I still don't see exactly what is the map from velocities $v \in TQ$ to momenta $p \in T^*Q$. Given an explicit position $q \in Q$ and a list of coefficients $\dot{q}^i$ in the expansion $v = \dot{q}^i(v) \frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}$, how exactly do we use the tautological one-form $\theta$ to figure out the corresponding momentum $(q,p|_q) \in T^*Q$?

Comment: The answer below is right, and actually, the same question was asked on MSE a few weeks ago [Canonical coordinates and tautological one-form: about a paragraph in the Wikipedia article on the Tautological One-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618136/568204).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statements are correct for me. However your final claim is not true, you need to be careful which manifolds are being identified.

The identifying map it gives is between $T(T^*M)$ and $T^*(T^*M)$. This is done by the symplectic structure. Taking the exterior derivative of the tautological one from, you get a two form on the cotangent bundle:
$$
\omega=d\theta
$$
The non degeneracy of $\omega$ induces at every $m\in T^*M$ an isomorphism between $T_m(T^*M)$ and $T_m^*(T^*M)$ given by:
$$
\alpha \in T_m(T^*M) \to \omega_m(\alpha,\cdot)\in T_m^*(T^*M)
$$
which extends to the entire manifolds $T(T^*M)$ and $T^*(T^*M)$.

However, this does not give an identification from $TM$ to $T^*M$. For this, you will need a Lagrangian (or conversely a Hamiltonian). Explicitly, given a Lagrangian $L$ defined on $TM$, its “partial derivative with respect to velocity” gives the map. Its inverse is constructed by constructing the Legendre transform of $L$, called the Hamiltonian, and taking the derivative with respect to conjugate momentum. Intuitively, you need to find a way to raise/lower the indices, which cannot be done only using the differential structure of $M$, you need something more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if the tautological one-form establishes an isomorphism between $TT^*M$ and $T^*T^*M$, instead of between $TM$ and $T^*M$, then why does the Wikipedia page say that "the tautological one-form assigns a numerical value to the momentum $p$ for each velocity $\dot{q}$"? Is the Wikipedia page just wrong?

Comment: Yes sorry typo, edited my answer

Comment: Well the wikipedia article is a bit misleading, especially the section “physical interpretation” which you are alluding to. What you quoted is correct, it’s merely a fancy description of the duality bracket. However, this does not mean that there is a natural isomorphism between the two spaces.

Comment: In general, when they use vague terms such as “correspondence” in the first paragraph, they are not referring to a natural isomorphism. They are rather referring to duality and its use to define the Legendre transform to go from Lagrangian to Hamiltonian description.

Comment: Btw, there a simple example of solder form does not come from the structure of cotangent bundle. Consider the case when phase space is a 2D sphere describing angular momentum of conserved magnitude.